# mybatis PooledDataSource performance tunning

Tags: spring, performance, oracle, websphere, mybatis

We configured the MyBatis connection pool like this.

```
[bean id="myDataSource"   class="org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource"]

    [property name="driver"        value="${driver}" /]
    [property name="url"                value="${url}" /]
    [property name="username"           value="${username}" /]
    [property name="password"           value="${password}" /]
    [property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="1000"/]
    [property name="poolMaximumIdleConnections" value="200"/]  
    [property name="poolMaximumCheckoutTime" value="20000"/]  
    [property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true"/]
    [property name="poolPingQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/]  
    [property name="poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="43200"/] 
    [property name="poolTimeToWait" value="30000"/]  

[/bean]
```

When the connection rate exceeds 50 connections per second, the server (WAS) can't process the requests fast enough.  This results in users repeatedly attempting to reload the page making the problem worse.

Our sites daily visitors are estimated about 20,000; and We have 1.2 Millions users.

Does anybody have a similar situation?
If then, how did you solve this problem?

We're using IBM WebSphere(WAS), Spring FrameWork, MyBatis, and Oracle. I think we have enough hardware.

Comment: What is the problem? Aren't the connections released? Don't you have enought request handling threads? Also this code what is it? It looks like a spring bean definition with some weird syntax... Have you tried another datasource? YOu have websphere why not let websphere handle the connections or try [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for instance.

Comment: If you would create that as Datasource in WebSphere you could actually monitor what is the pool usage, are there any thread waiting for connections or how long time takes the query. Did you monitor db statistics?